# Where can I get the CD-ROM content of Elasticity with Mathematica?

Tags: packages, reference-request

I found the CD-ROM link of this book [here](https://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=7065), but [this link](https://eng.ox.ac.uk/elasticity/) is invalid. Where should I get the CD-ROM content of this book?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this link](https://ppi-lms.polytechnique.fr/andrei.constantinescu/tools.html). I hope you enjoy. Hugs

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 11):

Some testing seems to indicate that the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/) was able to [save the relevant *Mathematica* files](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://eng.ox.ac.uk/elasticity/); at least, the packages are there intact. I'll let you try out if the notebooks are available as well.